# Change the values of a column based on another dataframe condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks something like this.

```
Var1    Var2
123     ADH6
123     ADH6
123     ADH6
123     ?
56756   CYP4V2
56756   ?
56756   ?
rs98    NUP62
rs98    ?
rs98    NUP62
rs98    NUP62
```

Var1 and var2 should be consistent 1 to 1. So whenever you have a value in var1 you should have the correspondant value in Var2.

It’s more clear if you visualize.

```
Var1    Var2
123     ADH6
123     ADH6
123     ADH6
123     ADH6
56756   CYP4V2
56756   CYP4V2
56756   CYP4V2
rs98    NUP62
rs98    NUP62
rs98    NUP62
rs98    NUP62
```

The problem is that I have thousands of different values. So I can’t create a rule for these specific cases, I need a rule that says something like: if Var2 is missing, then fill with the value of Var2 when same Var1.

In order to solve this, I though of, first, getting the average of the group var2, and creating a dataframe that would act as a dictionary. Then using this dictionary to fill the missing values.

I have this RepEx, but I miss the last part of the code:

```
library(dplyr)

first_column <- c("rs1","rs1","rs1","rs2","rs2","rs2","rs2","rs2","rs3","rs3","rs3","rs3","rs3")
second_column <- c("APOA","APOA",NA,"SIGMA",NA,NA,"SIGMA","SIGMA","SIGMA","ALPHA","ALPHA",NA,NA)

 
df <- data.frame(first_column, second_column)
df_noNa <- df[!is.na(df$second_column),]

df1 <- df_noNa %>%
  group_by(second_column) %>%
  count(first_column, second_column) %>%
  slice(which.max(n)) %>%
  select(-n)
```

Answer (score 2):

We coult group and use `fill`:

Update please see comment from onyambu(many thanks)

In order to address order issues: `.direction = "updown` or `.direction = "downup"`

```
library(tidyverse)

first_column <- c("rs1","rs1","rs1","rs2","rs2","rs2","rs2","rs2","rs3","rs3","rs3","rs3","rs3")
second_column <- c("APOA","APOA",NA,"SIGMA",NA,NA,"SIGMA","SIGMA","SIGMA","ALPHA","ALPHA",NA,NA)

df <- tibble(first_column, second_column)

df %>% 
  group_by(first_column) %>% 
  fill(second_column, .direction = "down")
```

```
   first_column second_column
   <chr>        <chr>        
 1 rs1          APOA         
 2 rs1          APOA         
 3 rs1          APOA         
 4 rs2          SIGMA        
 5 rs2          SIGMA        
 6 rs2          SIGMA        
 7 rs2          SIGMA        
 8 rs2          SIGMA        
 9 rs3          SIGMA        
10 rs3          ALPHA        
11 rs3          ALPHA        
12 rs3          ALPHA        
13 rs3          ALPHA
```

Comment: Thnks @TarJae. But what if the values are not ordered? Which is likely

Comment: @PassaroBagante in that case change the direction to `updown` or even `downup`. But this given code should definitely work